# Firebase query value in time range ordered by desc

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**My goal:**
I want to retrieve items from an infinite collection ordered by likes (descending). I also want to limit these results by date and result count, e.g. top 10.

Im not able to manage this case in a nice way propably. This is what I got so far, but I want only the top 10 results and this limitation is missing. If i place a `limit()` inside the query I dont get the correct results.

```
Timestamp get timeLimit {
    final limit = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 30));
    return Timestamp.fromDate(limit);
  }

QuerySnapshot snapshot = 
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('data')
    .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: timeLimit)
    .orderBy('date', descending: true)
    .get();

snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
              Data data = Data.fromJson(document.data());
              resultList.add(data);
              resultList.sort((a, b) => b.likes.compareTo(a.likes));
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting a limit of Cloud Firestore. If you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field. [Ref: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/order-limit-data]

In your case, the second orderBy (on `likes`) will have an effect only within groups of exactly the same `date`, which will be pretty useless.

---

### Brainstorming a solution.

#### (Any recommendation is welcome!)

If your goal is to keep track of the **daily / weekly / monthly TOP 10**, you should probably maintain that list in Firestore instead of computing the lists for each visitor.

You could have a Cloud Function running every [duration to be defined] to reset the TOP 10 lists.

This comes at a cost but the `read` operations will be dramatically cheaper for each visitor.

## !!! Attention, the following has not been tested.

Such a function could be written as:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();


exports.computeTopTenLists = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 hours').onRun((context) => {
  var millisecondsInOneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var dailyStart = new Date(Date.now() - millisecondsInOneDay);
  var weeklyStart = new Date(Date.now() - 7 * millisecondsInOneDay);
  var monthlyStart = new Date(Date.now() - 30 * millisecondsInOneDay);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);

  // Top 10 list (sorted by likes, descending)
  var dailyTopTen = [];
  var weeklyTopTen = [];
  var monthlyTopTen = [];

  db.collection('data').where("date", ">=", monthlyStart ).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    [
      { list: dailyTopTen, start: dailyStart },
      { list: weeklyTopTen, start: weeklyStart },
      { list: monthlyTopTen, start: monthlyStart },
    ].forEach((curr) => {
      curr.list.push(querySnapshot[0].data());
      querySnapshot.slice(1).forEach((doc) => {
        var data = doc.data();
        data['id'] = doc.id;
        if (data['date'] > curr.start && data['likes'] > curr.list[curr.list.length-1]) {
          curr.list.push(data);
          curr.list.sort((a, b) => (a.likes > b.likes ? -1 : 1));
          curr.list = curr.list.slice(0, 10);
        }
      });
    });
  })

  db.collection('top-ten').document('lists').set({
    daily: dailyTopTen.map(data => ({id: data['id'], title: data['title']})),
    weekly: weeklyTopTen.map(data => ({id: data['id'], title: data['title']})),
    monthlyly: monthlyTopTen.map(data => ({id: data['id'], title: data['title']})),
  });

  return null;
});
```

You would get the three Top 10 lists with just one document read.

Comment: thank you very much, I understand. Do you have an idea how to accomplish my goal? Getting top 10 liked items (desc) from day, week and month? How would you do it? Thanks alot!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do I get you right when you’re saying maintain, that you mean we have a collection with documents of the top 10 of the day week month? You’re saying we have a Limitation by querying with Date and likes. For me it’s still unclear how we can achieve that by query or maintain since there is the Limitation you’re talking about. Maybe it is easier to understand if you could provide me an example, I think that would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, you will still have the same limitation on your Firebase Cloud Function. However, since this function would run only once every X minutes/hours, you may afford to read all documents and compute the Top 10 lists.

Comment: Check my update. Try it. Fix the bugs if any and let me know. ATTENTION: I didn't take the time to test this Cloud Function.

Comment: thanks again for the answer. Meanwhile I have learned some more about the pricing model. Am I right that if we reset the 3 lists every day we only have around 30 reads to define the 30 entrys and again 1 read every time a client reaches the UI where the leaderboard is displayed? How much does running the cloud function itself cost? Waiting for you answer!

Comment: The number of reads will depend on how many data items you create per month. On top of the Reads/Writes on Firestore, the cost of running a single Cloud Function once per day is negligible. You get up to 2M FREE invocations per month, then it costs $0.40 per million invocations. I don't think you need to worry about the cost of one such Cloud Function. It will be orders of magnitude cheaper than the Reads/Writes caused by normal usage of your application.

Comment: alright perfect thanks alot. What do you mean with the number of reads will depend on the data items? I thought we would only pay for max 30 reads since the result for the 3 top 10 lists is 30?

Comment: If we are talking about the Cloud Function, the number of reads will be the input of the function, not the output. If you want to find the daily/weekly/monthly Top 10 amongst 1000 articles, the number of reads will be 1000. THEN, if we talk about the number of reads for each visitor, it could be just 1, because you can save the three Top 10 lists in the same document, probably as 3 arrays of maps containing, for each Top Article, its uid, title, imageURL, # likes, creation date, ... (current Firestore limit on document size: 1MiB)

Comment: Thierry thanks alot for making things clear. I didn't find the section where it says that the number of reads will be the input for the cloud functions, so I assume there will be some more informations which I didnt see yet. Could you provide me a link?

Comment: Sorry, some misunderstanding here. I just mean that the number of document read will depend on the result of `db.collection('data').where("date", ">=", monthlyStart ).get()` inside your Cloud Function.