# Firebase Firestore combine ordered value with date range

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Lets say we have a growing database of restaurants and users can like them. I want to show the 10 most liked restaurants of the month.

We do need a descended sort of restaurants and we need to define a range. Now as I stumbled over the firebase documentation, we are reaching a limit here. How would you implement that?

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = 
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('restaurants')
    .orderBy('likes', descending: true)
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .catchError((error) => print("---- $error"));
```

In my code example here we can accomplish the following:

```
[x] get all restaurants ordered by likes descending
[x] limit them to the top 10
[ ] only pick restaurants of the last 30 days
```

Lets say each restaurant has an `uploadDate` value which is a `Timestamp`. How can enclose our results to the `uploadDate` of last 30 days?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase query value in time range ordered by desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459288/firebase-query-value-in-time-range-ordered-by-desc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case to be able to compare it with the date, you would need to add something like the following:

```
final thirdyDaysAgo = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: -30));
...
.where('uploadDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(thirdyDaysAgo))
```

You first need to identify the date that was 30 days ago (or whichever one you need) and then convert it to the `Timestamp` and query it anywhere before you call `.get()`. I haven't tried putting just a `DateTime` object but it might work as well without converting the date to the `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a where() clause to your query
orderBy(...).where("uploadDate" >  ....)

The only catch is that since your are using two different fields ('likes' and 'uploadDates') ,you need to create a custom index. The good news is firestore error message will give you the exact index to build